# How to blacklist private dns resolution inside docker?

Tags: domain-name-system, docker, dnsmasq

### Problem

I want to block DNS resolutions that return private range IP addresses. What I've found so far is that to do such thing you need to setup a cache/recursive DNS server. However since I want to use it inside docker that's where I stumble upon difficulties.

The simplest way I found is using `dnsmasq` (as explained in this other [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/869334)). On the other hand just needs to run a single process so found out about `supervisord` which solves that issue. Nevertheless, created a sample docker image and when I use the localhost dns server (`dnsmasq`) by adding the flag `--dns 127.0.0.1` or replacing `/etc/resolv.conf` from within the container I get an error `** server can't find google.com: REFUSED` , which just makes sense after the warning I get at the time of running the container :

`WARNING: Localhost DNS setting (--dns=127.0.0.1) may fail in containers.`

### Environment

Sample docker image:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update &&\
    apt upgrade -y

RUN apt install -y supervisor \
    dnsmasq \
    dnsutils \
    iputils-ping \
    nano

RUN echo "stop-dns-rebind" > /etc/dnsmasq.d/stop-rebinding

COPY supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor.conf"]
```

supervisor.conf:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/dev/stdout
logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:dnsmasq]
command=dnsmasq --no-daemon
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Build:

```
sudo docker build . -t samplednsmasq
```

Run:

```
sudo docker run -it --dns 127.0.0.1 --rm samplednsmasq:latest
```

### Is it doable?

I would like to know if there is any way of making it work (without using multi-container like docker-compose) and dnsmasq, I'm also open to other alternatives that doesn't involve a dns caching server.

Solution:
Changed the `supervisor.conf` to:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/dev/stdout
logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:dnsmasq]
command=dnsmasq --no-daemon --interface=lo --stop-dns-rebind
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Also updated the Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update &&\
    apt upgrade -y

RUN apt install -y supervisor \
    dnsmasq \
    dnsutils \
    iputils-ping \
    nano \
    net-tools

RUN echo "listen-address=127.0.0.1\nbind-interfaces\nstop-dns-rebind" > /etc/dnsmasq.d/stop-rebinding &&\
    echo "\nserver=8.8.8.8\nserver=8.8.4.4\nno-resolv" >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf

COPY supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor.conf"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server can't find google.com: REFUSED` means that there is no DNS server listening on the specified address. By default `dnsmasq` won't listen on `127.0.0.1` address.

Comment: That could be a reason, however when I use `netstat` it shows that it's indeed listening (edited the post to include that info)

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not the same as `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Oh my bad, thought that using 0/0 would also include localhost, going to try forcing localhost thanks so far